# Use --dart-define-from-file with Xcode

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart, build

I set some env variables in a file named "keys.json" and used *--dart-define-from-file* to load them.

```
flutter run --dart-define-from-file=keys.json
```

It works properly by command line, but what about when using Xcode?

How can I set the *--dart-define-from-file* variable so I can run and build the project in Xcode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode will automatically pick up these values when you run the app from `.xcworkspace` with either `Debug` or `Release` configuration. Just make sure to run `flutter build ios --<debug/release> --dart-define-from-file <your_file.json>` before running the app from Xcode.

---

For those interested in how it works:

`flutter build` will regenerate the config files that Xcode uses internally: `Debug.xcconfig`, `Release.xcconfig` and `Generated.xcconfig`. By default, Xcode will use the debug configuration, but you can change that by editing your scheme in Xcode.

And if you look at the content of `Debug.xcconfig`

```
#include? "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig"
#include "Generated.xcconfig"
```

you will notice, that it references `Generated.xcconfig`. And somewhere inside this configuration file you will find that the build variable `DART_DEFINES` is set to some gibberish.

```
[...]
DART_DEFINES=YT0x,Yj0y,YT0x,Yj0y
[...]
```

This is nothing else then the base64-encoded version of a simple configuration file

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
}
```

This base64-encoded value is injected into your app and decoded by the flutter runtime ready to be used inside your app.

---

As of 2023/11/27, there is an ongoing discussion in the flutter community about whether the above behavior should be changed or even completely removed. Refer to GitHub issue [#138793](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/138793#issuecomment-1821923832) for a more up-to-date take on this topic.